# Missing 'Contacts' sync App

Tags: contacts, 4.2-jelly-bean

Am running Android 4.2.2 on a CUBOT smartphone, but cannot sync my contacts from Gmail as the ONLY sync adapters showing in the Settings-Accounts-Google section are 'App Data' and 'People details'.
Both these apps, if un-checked then checked pretty much instantly come back with a 'Last synced 14/10/2013 09:38' (or whatever time date-stamp is accurate), but nothing seems to have changed.
I seem to be missing just a plain old 'Contacts' sync option.
Being new to Android - I haven't a clue how to progress, or where to download/install 'contacts'. Advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Try [haxsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mots.haxsync&hl=en). It's the best. It's working on Android 4.2.

Comment: The question is about syncing Gmail contacts, and haxsync appears to be only for syncing Facebook data, so your answer doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score -2):

I've had the same problem but using CCleaner I solved it. I had too many registers of calls. Cleaning for 3 hours with CCleaner was the solution.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense -- what is "I had too many registers of calls" supposed to mean?  And why would CCleaner fix the issue?